# How to see current interface/wifi speed

Tags: networking, wireless, scripts, interface, download-speed

I can see the download and upload speed for all interfaces using `glances`. In the `network` section we can see the `Rx/s` and `Tx/s` columns where I can see the value in `Mbps`.

However I want to store this value in a variable. Is there any other command, which gives the current speed (`bps`, or `Kbps`, or `Mbps`) so that I can save that value in a variable in a bash script ?

I want to do this for `wlan0` interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single command to do this. However, you could use this:

```
eval $( \
    iwconfig wlan0 | \
    egrep -o 'Bit Rate=[0-9]+ [^ ]+' | \
    sed -e 's/ /_/;s/=/="/;s/$/"/' \
    )
echo $Bit_Rate
```

On my system, currently, I get:

```
$ eval $(iwconfig wlan0 | egrep -o 'Bit Rate=[0-9]+ [^ ]+' | sed -e 's/ /_/;s/=/="/;s/$/"/')
$ echo $Bit_Rate
54 Mb/s
```

`iwconfig wlan0` outputs a bunch of information about `wlan0` (try it and see).

Then `egrep` matches `"Bit Rate="`, followed by 1 or more digits, a blank, and 1 or more non-blanks. Because of the `-o` option, `egrep` outputs only the matched string.

`sed` then changes the first blank to an underscore, the `'='` to `'="'`, and the end-of-line to `'"'`, producing a string like `Bit_Rate="54 Mb/s"`.

`eval` then interprets that string in your current shell.

for further education, read

```
for i in iwconfig egrep sed bash ; do  
    man $i
done
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. however this value is always the same, and looks like it is the maximum rate. What I want to see is the actual current rate, which changes with time. Something like what can be seen when running `glances` . Please run `glances` , and see the `network` section.  It has `Rx`, and `Tx` which reflect the actual rate at a particular time. It is that value I want to store in the variable.

Comment: @sps I will not install `glances` to debug your problem.  You can adapt my answer to handle the output from `glances`.  Did you read the `man` pages I suggested? `man iwconfig` says, in part `"All  these  parameters and statistics are device dependent. Each driver  will provide only some of them depending on hardware support,  and  the range of values may change. Please refer to the man page of each device  for details."`

Comment: Ya I am  inside that for loop of man pages right now ... :) , ..